"dbt constraints" package is not accepting conditional arguments
When running DBT, my configuration in dbt_project.yml doesn't work for "dbt_constraints" package correctly. Based on the documentation given by "dbt_constraints" package maintainers, there's an argument to turn off dbt constraints completely:
vars:
    dbt_constraints_enabled: false

When using it this way as shown above, everything works and the package is not running and creating constraints. However, if I modify it a little bit - I need to have conditional arguments passed, meaning that for DEV env, it'll be "false" etc. My configuration is as follows: (note that we are using similar configuration for different variables and it works)
vars:
    dbt_constraints_enabled: |
        {%- if target.name in ['dev_airflow','dev_local'] -%} false
        {%- else -%} true
        {%- endif -%}

It shouldn't run only on DEV and DEV LOCAL, all other envs it should run.

I tried multiple ways of formatting the Jinja config - such as having "elif" instead of "else" and specifying all other envs. Then I also tried using lowercase, uppercase, camelcase.

I even created dbt model, that would check the variable current state, since I didn't know how to print var inside of Jinja. It was shown correctly in the model and constraints still ran. I've spent almost 10-15 hours trying to somehow get it to work but unsuccessfully.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

dbt_project.yml context works with a different syntax than the Jinja you would use in a dbt model. Here you have the docs. I would try with the following syntax:
vars:
    dbt_constraints_enabled: "{{ (false if target.name in ['dev_airflow','dev_local'] else true) | as_bool }}"


At this point I don't think it has to do with dbt_project.yml syntax rather than the dbt_constraints package alone. Even this solution didn't work and as I mentioned, we use the same syntax for other variables in dbt_project.yml. Only thing that works is that if I put false for dbt_constraints. Maybe this is a package specific problem or something is wrong in our repo, I'll try to create my new local dbt version and see if it works. Thanks anyway.

It shouldn't really be a package issue: this var should return either true or false in any case, and that's exactly what you're doing when hardcoding the false in there. I''ve updated the syntax in the proposed solution, I'd give it another go.

Yeah, that's what I'm thinking, but we're wrong, I tested it on dummy project from dbt and it still doesn't work, so the only thing that comes up to me is the package itself. See for yourself: 1st run with the conditional config - https://imgur.com/a/UMmYlEG and 2nd run with "false" value -  https://imgur.com/a/VKk8xQ4
